# Why Samsung Adaptive brightness is using camera?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-camerax, samsung-galaxy, samsung-mobile-sdk

As I work on developing an Android application that involves camera functionality, I've encountered a perplexing issue on my Samsung test device. Specifically, when adaptive brightness is enabled, an ongoing influx of logs continues even after I've exited the camera and remain within my application. Curiously, this behaviour persists across all versions of CameraX that I've tested (Seems to be an issue in Samsung devices). I'm eager to know if anyone has insights into Samsung's rationale for intertwining camera usage with adaptive brightness. Additionally, I'm curious if other developers have encountered similar log-related occurrences when implementing CameraX in their applications.

```
2023-08-07 10:44:16.722 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:16.735 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:17.713 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:17.777 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:22.844 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:22.855 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:23.839 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:23.897 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:28.967 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:28.988 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:29.953 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:30.006 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:35.056 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:35.068 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
2023-08-07 10:44:36.040 17070-19345 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.cam.sam            I  Camera 3 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2User Id 0
```